# Generating random diagonally dominant dense/sparse matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a matlab command for generating a random n by n matrix, with elements taken in the interval [0,1], with x% of the entries on the off-diagonal to be 0. Then, additionally setting the element in the diagonal to be the sum of every element in its respective column? In order to create a diagonally dominant dense/sparse matrix? This may be easy enough to write a code for but I was wondering if there was already a built in function with this capability.

---

**EDIT:**

I am new to Matlab/programming so this was an easier said than done. I'm having trouble making the matrix with the percentage ignoring the diagonal. It's a n x n matrix, so there are $n^2$ entries, with n of them on the diagonal, I want the percentage of zeros to be taken from $n^2 - n$ elements, i.e. all the off-diagonal elements. I cannot implement this correctly. I do not know how to initialize my M (see below) to correspond correctly.

```
% Enter percentage as a decimal
function [M] = DiagDomSparse(n,x)
M = rand(n);
disp("Original matrix"); 
disp(M);  
x = sum(M); 
for i=1:n
   for j=1:n
      if(i == j)
         M(i,j) = x(i);
      end
   end
end
disp(M);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done. But a few parts of your request probably need more details about the underlying maths.

Comment: No, there is no such function in MATLAB that I know of. But you don't need more than a few lines of code to implement this. It seems less effort to implement it than to ask this question. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I tried implementing it and cannot seem to get my percentage of zeros correctly. If its an easy fix could you please advise.

Comment: Do you need exactly a specific fraction of elements to be 0, or do you need each element to have a certain probability of being 0?

Comment: I need a specific fraction of elements to be 0.

Comment: For example, say the matrix is 10 by 10, so there are 100 entries, but 10 of those are on the diagonal, so 90 would be the denominator of the fraction. Then, if I were to input 50%, I would only expect 45 (random) elements all on the off-diagonal to be 0. A roof function could be implements for the case where x% times n^2 - n isn't an integer. Like if I wanted 15% instead of 50% of the 90 elements to be 0, that would be 13.5, so we could take 14 elements to be 0.

Comment: @Dragonite: please tag me when you reply, I didn't get notified!

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Sorry!

Comment: No need for apologies, I wanted you to be aware that it's not always obvious when notifications are sent out... I had been thinking about this problem overnight, I've posted the solution I came up with. It's straight-forward but not pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach that you could use. I'm sure you will get some other answers now with a more clever approach, but I like to keep things simple and understandable.

What I'm doing below is creating the data to be put in the off-diagonal elements first. I create an empty matrix and copy this data into the off-diagonal elements using linear indexing. Now I can compute the sum of columns and write those into the diagonal elements using linear indexing again. Because the matrix was initialized to zero, the diagonal elements are still zero when I compute the sum of columns, so they don't interfere.

```
n = 5;
x = 0.3; % fraction of zeros in off-diagonal
k = round(n*(n-1)*x); % number of zeros in off-diagonal

data = randn(n*(n-1)-k,1); % random numbers, pick your distribution here!
data = [data;zeros(k,1)];  % the k zeros
data = data(randperm(length(data))); % shuffle

diag_index = 1:n+1:n*n; % linear index to all diagonal elements
offd_index = setdiff(1:n*n,diag_index); % linear index to all other elements
M = zeros(n,n);
M(offd_index) = data; % set off-diagonal elements to data
M(diag_index) = sum(M,1); % set diagonal elements to sum of columns
```

Comment: this was so helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To refer to the diagonal you want eye(n,'logical'). Here is a solution:

```
n=5;
M = rand(n);
disp("Original matrix"); 
disp(M);
x = sum(M); 
for i=1:n
   for j=1:n
      if(i == j)
         M(i,j) = x(i);
      end
   end
end
disp('loop solution:')
disp(M);
M(eye(n,'logical'))=x;
disp('eye solution:')
disp(M);
```